# learning_tf turtlesim tutorial: second turtle twirling

Tags: ros, tf-tutorial, learning-tf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have followed the tf tutorials and implemented all the instructions to get the second turtle to follow the first turtle which in turn is controlled via the keyboard, however, when I launch the start_demo.launch, the second turtle starts twirling continuously even without moving the first turtle.

When I move the first turtle, I can see that the second turtle changes its movement slightly while still rotating. I am not sure what the problem is. I have attached an image showing the pdf file created by rosrun tf view_frames and the turtlesim. Heres what I get:

$ rosrun tf view_frames
Listening to /tf for 5.000000 seconds
Done Listening
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
dot - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)

Detected dot version 2.26.3
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
frames.pdf generated

Any help would be much appreciated.

regards,

Khalid

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52532/learning_tf-turtlesim-tutorial:-second-turtle-twirling/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the same issue as in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/45770/turtle_tf_demolaunch-goes-wrong-when-replaced-with-c-compiled-nodes/#47893) and [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/45884/turtle-tf-tutorial-fails-to-work/).

The dummy thread stuff is just a python bug that does no harm.  Here's the [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3950). Supposedly, ubuntu will distribute the fix in the future.  There's a patch for it out there if you really want to fix it, though.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-17**:
Thanks alot. the problem is fixed now by replacing transform.setRotation(  tf::Quaternion(msg->theta,0, 0) ); with transform.setRotation(  tf::Quaternion(0, 0, msg->theta) ); in the turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp